# Naming column name as '&CID=4859615 &SUBID=197378' in google big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to name a column in big query as '&CID=4859615 &SUBID=197378'. So the query looks like below

Select customer_id as &CID=4859615 &SUBID=197378 from cust_table

is it possible to use such naming in google big query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to use such naming in google big query?

It is not possible in BigQuery!

```
Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start 
with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long
```

If you think you really need this  - you can use below

```
Select customer_id as `CID_4859615_SUBID_197378` from cust_table
```